# Remove border lines from QFrame & QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

Please have a look at the attached image to understand the problem. In the image you can see, how can I remove the border lines or set their color to the QDialog color. Thanks.

[image: Image showing lines]

Answer (score 26):

Try setting the QTabWidget Stylesheet to have 0 border.

So for instance:

```
tabwidget.setStyleSheet("QTabWidget::pane { border: 0; }");
```

Comment: Must have did an hour of different settings with no results. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

using qt designer, click on the frame, go to property name stylesheet type border:0

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score 1):

Just add  `tabwidget.setDocumentMode(True)`